# .htaccess image path redirect to server root

Tags: html, image, apache, .htaccess, redirect

My website root was at: http://myurl.com/new

All my images were linked as: http://myurl.com/new/image.png, which was the real image path at that time.

But now I've moved my website root to just plain http://myurl.com. So all the images are
still pointing to the old urls.

Without changing the path of every image on the website, can I use htaccess to redirect all image requests to my website root?

For e.g:
`<img src="new/image.png">` - should actually be `<img src="image.png">`

Thanks,

Kaushik

Comment: Depends on whether you are using a CMS or if you are using a wysiwyg editor or if you have created all links yourself minus any template.

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^[0-9A-Za-z]{12}/([^.]+\.(?:js|jpg|png))$ /$1 [L,NC]
```

You can try with this htaccess

Answer (score 0):

This rule in `DOcumentRoot/.htaccess` should take care of all the image/css/js file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^new/(.+?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js))$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Make sure this is your very first rule.